# Subsonic 3 Save() then Update()?

Tags: subsonic3

I need to get the primary key for a row and then insert it into one of the other columns in a string.

So I've tried to do it something like this:

```
newsObj = new news();
newsObj.name = "test"
newsObj.Save();
newsObj.url = String.Format("blah.aspx?p={0}",newsObj.col_id);
newsObj.Save();
```

But it doesn't treat it as the same data object so newsObj.col_id always comes back as a zero. Is there another way of doing this? I tried this on another page and to get it to work I had to set `newsObj.SetIsLoaded(true);`

This is the actual block of code:

```
page p;

if (pageId > 0)
    p = new page(ps => ps.page_id == pageId);
else
    p = new page();

if (publish)
    p.page_published = 1;

if (User.IsInRole("administrator"))
    p.page_approved = 1;

p.page_section = staticParent.page_section;
p.page_name = PageName.Text;
p.page_parent = parentPageId;
p.page_last_modified_date = DateTime.Now;
p.page_last_modified_by = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
p.Add();
string urlString = String.Empty;
if (parentPageId > 0)
{
    urlString = Regex.Replace(staticParent.page_url, "(.aspx).*$", "$1");  // We just want the static page URL (blah.aspx)          
    p.page_url = String.Format("{0}?p={1}", urlString, p.page_id);
}
p.Save();
```

If I hover the p.Save(); I can see the correct values in the object but the DB is never updated and there is no exception.
Thanks!

Comment: Is your PK int (identity) or something else like GUID?

Comment: In one case it wasn't and that ended up being the issue. In another case... it is and will only work if I do something like: new page(ps => ps.page_id == pageId);

Comment: I think this is the only way to do it. If you have an auto-number (identity in sql server, sequence in Oracle, etc.) for your PK, then you'll might need to refresh the object by doing a query after saving it. I've moved to almost all GUID values, so I can just create my PK via code, set the value, then Save().

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem with that :

po oPo = new po();

oPo.name  ="test";

oPo.save(); //till now it works.

oPo.name = "test2";

oPo.save(); //not really working, it's not saving the data since isLoaded is set to false 
and the columns are not considered dirty.

it's a bug in the ActiveRecord.tt for version 3.0.0.3.

In the method public void Add(IDataProvider provider)
immediately after SetIsNew(false); 
there should be : SetIsLoaded(true);

the reason why the save is not working the second time is because the object can't get dirty if it is not loaded. By adding the SetIsLoaded(true) in the ActiveRecord.tt, when you are going to do run custom tool, it's gonna regenerate the .cs perfectly.