# Why isn't IsLoaded set to true upon Save()?

Tags: c#, subsonic, subsonic3

```
var user = new User()
{
    Username = "a",
    Password = "b",
};

user.Save();

Console.WriteLine(user.ID)         // prints "504"
Console.WriteLine(user.IsLoaded()) // prints "false"
```

If the `ID` property is automatically set on `Save()`, I would expect `IsLoaded()` to also be set (to `true`).  Why is it my responsibility to call `user.SetIsLoaded(true);`?

(I realize I can just edit `ActiveRecord.tt` to get this working, but maybe I just don't understand what `IsLoaded()` actually represents.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IsLoaded` states that the record you are looking at represents data in the database. This is for example used to detect that a record is dirty. `IsLoaded == false` records cannot get dirty because they do not represent data in the database. `IsLoaded == true` does, so changing properties on such a record sets it dirty and you can save the record again.

[Subsonic 3 Save() then Update()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402187/subsonic-3-save-then-update) also describes some details on this.